# How i can Use Php value as a an ID for carsoule Slider

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a slider dynamic according to a php value like i am calling same slider for related and upsells product if i use a static ID its not working to i decide to use a php value as a slider id like

```
var owl = $("#<?php echo $myValue?>");
```

now i my html i am calling same slider as

```
<ol id="owl-demo1" class="products list items product-items" style="display: inline-flex !important;">
```

it is not working need help how to do this correctly

Comment: `<?php $myValue?>` doesn't do anything by itself, you forgot the `echo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
<ol id="<?php echo $myValue; ?>-demo1" class="products list items product-items" style="display: inline-flex !important;">
```